# How to do HTTPS pipe-line in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, http, https, pipeline

I'm using the net-http-pipeline gem to do HTTP pipe-lining for my project, and everything works great. But now one of the API providers changed to HTTPS and everything is breaking. Is there a way to do HTTPS pipe-lining in Ruby?

Comment: It's probably because the gem is not prepared to deal with the secure socket layer that HTTPS adds, I'd suggest using another gem or modifying it yourself.

Comment: FWIW, people who know seem to be questioning whether or not  pipelining is actually a good thing in today's internet. References: http://www.guypo.com/technical/http-pipelining-not-so-fast-nor-slow/ and https://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/macvittie/archive/2009/04/02/http-pipelining-a-security-risk-without-real-performance-benefits.aspx ... why not just keep the benefits of keep-alive connections without the complexity of pipelining your requests?